# Can a Firestore query with .where() perform an empty search

Tags: typescript, firebase, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore, querying

I'm building a website to upload old exams and have a bunch of documents with fields like teacher, year, class, ... . These are all stored in cloud Firestore. I use the .where("Teacher", "==", teacher) to filter the data. I would however like to be able to perform an empty query, so that a search can return multiple math tests, that aren't necessarily from the same teacher. Is there a way to do this with the .where() operator or do I have to separate every search case?

Comment: What do you mean by "empty query"?  What exactly are you trying to retrieve?

Comment: Basically I want it, unless otherwise specified, to return everything. I solved this by specifying different search cases (like only field A and C given). However if you have a simpler solution I would be interested in hearing it

Comment: @MichaelKeller did you find a solution? There must be a more elegant solution right?

Answer (score 2):

To get all documents in a collection, simply use the [get() method on a CollectionReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference#get):

```
const firestore = firebase.firestore()
const coll = firestore.collection('collection_name')
coll.get().then(querySnapshot => {
    // Iterate querySnapshot.docs here
})
```

CollectionReference subclasses Query, which means that a CollectionReference is itself already a query that has no constraints.